# How to remove TextField bottom line in Jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, textfield

here is my code:

```
TextField(
        value = text,
        onValueChange = { onValueChanged(it) },
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(100.dp)
            .padding(10.dp)
            .border(width = 1.dp, color = Color.Gray, shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)),
        singleLine = false,
        placeholder = { Text("Enter some text here") }
    )
```

It works fine, but I got a bottom line out of the border area. How to remove this line?

Comment: Your "border" looks like you should be going for an `OutlinedTextField`, which wouldn't have this issue?

Comment: @m.reiter that is exactly what I want

Comment: I'll rewrite this as an answer, so you can accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `OutlinedTextField` offers exactly what you would like to achieve:

- border
- no underline

It's part of Material2 & Material3.
For more details see https://m3.material.io/components/text-fields/overview#38269950-ca0b-40b3-a884-64dfac22a1ef

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in Material 3 design webpage, the underline color of the TextField is the indicator, so you can change the color of the indicator to transparent.

`colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors( focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent, unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent)`

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change color of background color to transparent or to something that matches your background. Let me know if that helps

```
TextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = { onValueChanged(it) },
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(100.dp)
        .padding(10.dp)
        .border(
            width = 1.dp,
            color = Color.Gray,
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)
        )
        .background(Color.Transparent), <- Set background color to transparent / Color. White
    singleLine = false,
    placeholder = { Text("Enter some text here") }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

For custom text fields you can use a `BasicTextField` and build from there your custom text field or use this `BasicTextField` inside a `Surface` or any other composable for example:

```
  BasicTextField(
        value = textField, onValueChange = { onTextFieldChange(it) },
        textStyle = TextStyle(
            fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.manrope_semi_bold)),
            fontSize = 20.sp,
            color = appGray,
            textAlign = TextAlign.End
        ),
        enabled = true,
        singleLine = true,
        maxLines = 1,
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number),
        keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
            onNext = {
                focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Down)
            },
            onDone = {
                focusManager.clearFocus()
            }
        ),
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
    )
```